# Combination of breakdowns not working in Facebook Api v 7.0

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-graph-api

**Request**:
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me?fields=adaccounts{insights.breakdowns(device_platform, publisher_platform, age){clicks,impressions}}

**Response:**
"message": "(#100) Current combination of data breakdown columns (action_type, age, device_platform, publisher_platform) is invalid "

**My Problem**:
The breakdown column action_type is not present in the request, why get me this error? It's possible to get insights of campaign for examp

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns#combiningbreakdowns

Comment: Thanks for comment, i read the offical docuemntation, but is impossible for me to know the reason of this error.

Comment: My question is: Is possible to get insights with breakdowns "device_platform, publisher_platform, age"?

Comment: They _explain_ there, that you can not use just any arbitrary permutations of breakdowns. _“My question is:”_ - and the fact that you got this error message, has not already answered that for you? Make separate requests then - the first two together do not throw this error, so make one request for those, and a second one for the `age` breakdown …